# File not being forwarded to Handler

Tags: php, python, apache, apache2, cgi

OK, so I've set up 2 actions for 2 different file types, like this :

```
<IfModule mime_module>
AddHandler application/x-httpd-lgm .lgm
Action application/x-httpd-lgm /cgi-bin/lgm
</IfModule>
```

The second one (not working), just next to the above one in the `apache2.conf`

```
<IfModule mime_module>
AddHandler application/x-httpd-lhtml .lhtml
Action application/x-httpd-lhtml /cgi-bin/ilgmc
</IfModule>
```

Which actually ends up forwarding `.lgm` files to my `lgm` interpreter (as a parameter).

However, this does not happen for the `.lhtml` files, although I've done the exact same thing. The `ilgmc` interpreter gets called but without any parameter (in `argv`).

What's going on? What am I missing?

---

**Specs :**

- Apache2
- Debian Wheezy

Comment: This doesn't appear to relate to C++, C, or Python. Perhaps you could fix your tags and/or explain the context?

Comment: @AlanStokes Well, it actually relates to none of them (and maybe it relates to all of them... lol that was quite cryptic). I've written an interpreter (pretty much along the lines of php/python/ruby) and I'm trying to forward requests (e.g. file `index.lgm`) to my executable. The whole thing does work in one case, but doesn't work in the last one. And I'm still rather perplexed... *(P.S. I'm by no means an Apache configuration guru, so...)*